# Calculate different Standard errors depending on Group / condition

Tags: r

I want to calculate the standard error of means (SEM) for a data set. However, the sample size is different among the Groups (n= 8 for WT, n= 9 for KO) so I need a conditional formula. Here's a minimal example of my data :

```
Experiment <- c("A", "C", "D")
Group <- c("KO", "WT", "KO")
Mean <- c(23, 41, 32)
sd <- c(2, 3, 4)
df <- data.frame(Experiment, Group, Mean, sd)
df
```

yields:

```
 Experiment Group Mean sd
1          A    KO   23  2
2          C    WT   41  3
3          D    KO   32  4
```

I tried

```
df$SEM <- if (df$Group == "KO") {
  df$sd /sqrt(9)
} else {
  df$sd /sqrt(8)
}
```

but this calculates SEM with 9 for all Groups.

Comment: Use `ifelse` i.e. `ifelse(df$Group == 'KO', df$sd/sqrt(9), df$sd/sqrt(8))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@akrun's suggestion in the comments (use `ifelse`) is a good one, but I'd encourage you to be a little bit more explicit and add the sample size to the data set first:

```r
df <- transform(df, sampsize = ifelse(Group=="KO", 9, 8)
df <- transform(df, SEM = sd/sqrt(sampsize))
```

You can also do this by prepending `df$` throughout (`df$sampsize <- ifelse(df$Group=="KO", 9, 8); etc.`), or with `dplyr::mutate()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- mutate(df,
        sampsize=ifelse(Group=="KO", 9, 8),
        sem = sd/sqrt(sampsize)
     )
```

This way it's a little more obvious what's going on when you come back and read your code in a few months (you *might* immediately recognize the formula for the SEM, but you might not ...)